# Avoid Multiple calls to GetUser when using ASP.NET Membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am using ASP.NET Membership in an ASP.NET MVC 3 Web application project.

I have installed the ASP.NET Membership tables using `Aspnet_regsql.exe` and now my main `userTable` has a foriegn key called "userID" which points to the "UserId" of aspnet_Users.

This "userTable" is connected to many tables. So for every operation now I require the "UserId" from aspnet_User using the username with which the user has logged in.

For this I use

```
 MembershipUser user = Membership.Provider.GetUser(username, true);
```

now for each and every operation I have to make this call and get `user.ProviderUserKey` to continue with my other operations.

I am thinking there has to be a better way to do this. Is any any built in way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.NET Membership Provider isn't intended to provide the ProviderUserKey... perhaps you could use the username instead? You can always easily access that through Context.User.Identity.Name.

Answer (score 0):

I always use:

```
Guid userId = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
```

Comment: that be sending multiple calls to database right ? which is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: You can save provideruserkey in cookie maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You get the user information once and put it in **forms authentication cookie** with user data encrypted.

For subsequent calls you use **Context.Identity** for the user information

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the relevant information around in the cache, for example in a `Dictionary<string, Guid>` where the key is the user name (which you can lookup using HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name or Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name), and the ProviderUserKey is the value.

Build this dictionary either on-demand or initialize it once, and put it in the ASP.NET Cache, Session or Application (of course watch our for serialization and concurrency issues).